# highstocks intraday chart with timestamp and non decimal y axis

Tags: highcharts, timestamp

Have a highstock chart with a large number of data around 60-80 thousand timestamp and sum. The problem is that none of the data which i give to highstock contains decimal but highstock shows some values that are decimals like 1.5 but my data does not have any 1.5. Does the highstock averages the data if timestamp is more than 1hour or anything? If it does averages the data than how to stop this averaging as i dont need decimal data

var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

```
    chart: {
        height: 400
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Tweets Count'
    },


xAxis: {
     gapGridLineWidth: 0,
     events: {
     afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
     min=e.min
     max=e.max
     src="http://34.66.198.6/"+id+"/map/"+parseInt(min).toString()+"/"+parseInt(max).toString()+"/"
     loadIframe("map",src)
     src="http://34.66.198.6/"+id+"/hashtags/"+parseInt(min).toString()+"/"+parseInt(max).toString()+"/"
     loadIframe("hashtags",src)
     src="http://34.66.198.6/"+id+"/mentions_screen_name/"+parseInt(min).toString()+"/"+parseInt(max).toString()+"/"
     loadIframe("mentions_screen_name",src)
     src="http://34.66.198.6/"+id+"/screen_name/"+parseInt(min).toString()+"/"+parseInt(max).toString()+"/"
     loadIframe("screen_name",src)
     src="http://34.66.198.6/"+id+"/sentiments/"+parseInt(min).toString()+"/"+parseInt(max).toString()+"/"
     loadIframe("sentiments",src)
     src="http://34.66.198.6/"+id+"/sentiments/"+parseInt(min).toString()+"/"+parseInt(max).toString()+"/All/all"
     loadIframe("twitter",src)
     src="http://34.66.198.6/"+id+"/sentiments/"+parseInt(min).toString()+"/"+parseInt(max).toString()+"/All/all/word"
     loadIframe("word-cloud",src)
         }
     }
 },

yAxis:{
 text:'Tweets Count'
 }
```

,
       rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'hour',
                count: 1,
                text: '1H'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1D'
            },
{
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1M'
            },
{
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1Y'
            },
            {
                type: 'all',
                count: 1,
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 1,
            inputEnabled: false
        },

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Tweets Count',
        data: {{data}},
        type: 'area',
        gapSize: 5,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {
                x1: 0,
                y1: 0,
                x2: 0,
                y2: 1
            },
            stops: [
                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
        },
        threshold: null
    }], 

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    height: 300
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: null
                },
                navigator: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: If i zoom into the data the decimal values are gone and my actual data shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highstock provides `dataGrouping` feature, which is enabled by default.

Please check the docs below and compare the result with:

- disabled `dataGrouping`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tokz3aum/
- enabled `dataGrouping` http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/co16j85p/

You can disable `dataGrouping` or define your own `approximation` function which will round the result, for example:

```
series: [{
    data: [...],
    dataGrouping: {
        approximation: function(arr) {
            var len = arr.length,
                ret = Highcharts.approximations.sum(arr);

            if (Highcharts.isNumber(ret) && len) {
                ret = ret / len;
            }

            return Math.round(ret);
        }
    }
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q6ukvrp9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.approximation

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping